# OneLiner explanation - Python

Tags: python, arrays, one-liner

I have a task in LeetCode called **832. Flipping an Image**

> Given an n x n binary matrix image, flip the image horizontally, then
> invert it, and return the resulting image.
>
> To flip an image horizontally means that each row of the image is
> reversed.
>
> For example, flipping [1,1,0] horizontally results in [0,1,1]. To
> invert an image means that each 0 is replaced by 1, and each 1 is
> replaced by 0.
>
> For example, inverting [0,1,1] results in [1,0,0].
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: image = [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]
>
> Output:[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,1]]
>
> Explanation:
>
> First reverse each row: [[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]].
> Then, invert the image:[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,1]]

and the solution provided by someone is a one-liner in Python:

```
class Solution:
def flipAndInvertImage(self, image: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
    return [[1 ^ i for i in reversed(row)] for row in image]
```

And debugging the one-liner is not effective at all so my kind request is to explain blow-by-blow the code. Mostly I have problems with those parts before **for loop** as I couldn't find an explanation on the internet that you can put a code before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class Solution:
```

Defines the Class solution

```py
def flipAndInvertImage(self, image: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
```

Defines the `flipAndInvertImage` function with one Argument of a list of lists of integers, and the Output of the Same type.

Okay now the oneliner:

```py
return [[1 ^ i for i in reversed(row)] for row in image]
```

This is called a generator expression, where in

```py
a = [int(i) for i in list_of_strings]
```

for example, you Loop over `list_of_strings` and then apply the function `int()` to it. It's rougly similar to doing this:

```py
a = []
for i in list_of_strings:
    a.append(int(i))
```

So `[[...] for row in image]` ist the First Generator expression and makes the variable `row` loop over the rows inside the Image array.

`[1 ^ i for i in reversed(row)]` is the second/inner generator. It loops over the variable row given by the outer generator, reverses it using the `reverse()` function, and then applies a binary x-or operation to it. All `1 ^ i` does, is make ones into zeros and zeros into ones.